# nnet package - is it neccessary to scale data?

Tags: r, neural-networks

Could you tell me is it necessary to scale data ?
I am using this package for prediction.
Not scaled data give the same efficiency of prediction as scaled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *required* to normalize data for neural network models, but it is *advised*, as training will take longer (weights have to compensate for differences across features) or might also give you different/worse results without normalization (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674623/why-do-we-have-to-normalize-the-input-for-an-artificial-neural-network) for some more details).

Obtaining the same efficiency with and without normalization is possible, but the underlying model can still be different. For example, here's a simple example using `nnet` in `caret::train` with and without data normalization that will give you different nets and performance over parameter sets - while still having similar optimal performance on CV partitions then:

```
    library(caret)
    m  <- train(x = iris[,1:4], y = iris[,5],
                method = 'nnet', metric = 'Kappa', 
                tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=1:8, decay=3**(-6:1)),
                trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', 
                                        number = 10, 
                                        repeats = 10, 
                                        returnResamp = 'final'))

    mScaled <- train(x = (iris[,1:4]), y = iris[,5],
                        method = 'nnet', metric = 'Kappa', 
                        preProcess = c('center', 'scale'),
                        tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=1:8, decay=3**(-6:1)),
                        trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', 
                                                number = 10, 
                                                repeats = 10, 
                                                returnResamp = 'final'))

    m$finalModel
    mScaled$finalModel
    plot(m)
    plot(mScaled)
    boxplot(data.frame(m$resample$Kappa, mScaled$resample$Kappa))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you tell me what does mean softmax parameter mean ? And decay

Comment: Using one of the linout, entropy, softmax or censored parameter changes the output layer, which by default is logistic regression. Using the decay parameter enables weight decay (a form of regularization, limiting what weights can become in neural networks, therefore their power). You should probably read up upon details of those concepts.